# Is there a difference between dictionary['a'] = 1 and dictionary.update({'a':1})?

Tags: python

In Python, You can either do `a={}` or `a=dict()` to make a dictionary,

and `a['a'] = 1` or `a.update({'a':1})` to add a component.

Which I think does the exactly the same thing.

I am curious if there is any difference between those two ways of dealing with dictionary.

It seems a little different from how a list is handled since you can also make a list either `a = []` or `a = list()`, but can't do `a[0] = 1` while `a.append(1)` works fine.

Is it simply just a different way of doing things? or is there any difference?

Comment: Well, `[] =` sets a specific key to a specific value. `update` takes another dict and sets all its keys and values. That's something of a difference… For single values, the result is the same though.

Comment: `a.update({'a':1})` creates a totally unnecessary `dict` with a single key-value pair. Generally, you use `.update` if you *already have a `dict`* with which to update another dict

Comment: Also, `list` and `dict` objects are different, one is a sequence, the other is a mapping. They will have different interfaces.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then is `a={}` and `a=dict()`  
 exactly the same? or Is there like a difference in memory usage or something like that?

Comment: @BerryMan No, not *exactly* but essentially, although one is a literal and the other is a type constructor call, so the constructor call will be a lot slower.

Comment: @BerryMan and note, in general, literal syntax works different than the constructor call, which will take as an argument an iterable of pairs and consume it. A literal is, well, a literal.